# File copy to USB3 HDD slows down after 16GB

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I recently bought an external USB3 case for my old hard disk and formatted it with UDF to backup stuff from my Ubuntu 14.04 and OSX machines. This works fine and I got speeds of 50MB/s and over when writing "small" files under Linux. 
However, I have troubles with one particular file that is about 21GB in size.

It is transferring normally until 16GB have been copied. After that, cp starts using 100% CPU (only a single core, though) and transfer rate is only around 500K/s according to iotop. Meaning it will take ages to copy the remaining 5GB.

The other thing I noticed. When this happens and the external disk is connected to the same USB root as my Wifi dongle, network becomes completely unusable.

Here's cp using 100% CPU

```
top - 20:07:46 up  5:25,  4 users,  load average: 1,01, 1,05, 0,98
Tasks: 225 total,   2 running, 223 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1,0 us, 25,2 sy,  0,0 ni, 73,7 id,  0,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   8118248 total,  7993696 used,   124552 free,   316844 buffers
KiB Swap:  7811064 total,        0 used,  7811064 free.  5673408 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
15975 kai       20   0   19520   2524   2368 R 100,0  0,0  24:20.01 cp
```

And here's the output from iotop

```
Total DISK READ :     504.39 K/s | Total DISK WRITE :     382.23 K/s
Actual DISK READ:     504.39 K/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND          
15975 be/4 kai       504.39 K/s  382.23 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % cp -a -v ~2.0.8.sh .
```

Have the same symptoms when copying the file using nautilus, btw.

Any idea what might be causing this, or how to go about to track the issue down?

Comment: Do add yourself to bug # 1208993, Ubuntu slows down and hangs while copying files from/to USB.

Comment: Came across that one too, in yesterdays search for answers. Even tried the /etc/sysctl.conf tweak (to no avail). Besides, the symptoms appear to be different. The system does remain responsive (aside from the wifi, which is explicable), it's only the transfer operation itself that slows to a crawl.